# Is there a way to check which UE version was used to create a project?

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-development-kit

When opening a project, it complains about it being created using a different version of Unreal. I obviously get a bunch of compile errors if I go through with opening it anyway.

Is there a way to check what version was used to create it?

I was hopeful when I saw the EngineAssociation entry inside the uproject file but it ended up being meaningless to me

```
{
    "FileVersion": 3,
    "EngineAssociation": "{0004AAA1-08D6-A558-739F-534E0C642FD2}",
    "Category": "",
    "Description": "",
    "TargetPlatforms": [
        "PS4",
        "WindowsNoEditor"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This means that the project was associated with a custom version of the engine, manually built using the source code of the engine downloaded from GitHub. You can not tell just from looking at the `.uproject` file which version of the engine this custom build is based on.

In vanilla builds of the engine, the `EngineAssociation` field holds a meaningful value, e.g. "4.24"

Comment: This also happens with official releases for Linux. I've been using the 5.1.0, and what I see inside my `.uproject` is an UUID. :/